# New line in json array is getting converted to a comma | nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, post

I am relatively new to nodejs and running into an issue while parsing a Json post request.

Here is the JSON format of the post request:

```
{"parameters":{"issuerId":[96409],"source":["'XYZ'"]}}
```

And here is my code to read it.

```
function getSearchData(req, res, next) {
  console.log("req is" + req.body);

  try {
JSON.parse(reqJSON);
    } catch (e) {
console.log(e);
 }

}
```

This parsing works fine and I am able to parse it and do my further logic. However, if I change my format of post request(same request with additional new lines) it fails to parse as it adds additional commas in place of each new line in the request.

```
{  
  "parameters": {  
    "issuerId": [96409],
    "source":["'XYZ'"]
  }
}
```

Here's the output from the code with the second request.

`req is{,"parameters":{"id":[96409],,"source":["'XYZ'"]}}
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,]`

If you notice, an extra comma gets added at each new line, which was never in the request to begin with.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: JSON.parse(reqJSON); is reqJSON a string?

Comment: I initially thought it to be a json object but it wasn't. So I tried to parse it to a Json object using JSON.parse and I guess that is what the issue is. New lines in strings are getting converted to extra commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never have to parse the JSON yourself, unless you're concatenating the request body stream yourself.

Hint 1: Do you use any framework like Express? Do you use body parser?

Hint 2: How do you create the JSON?

Hint 3: Do you use correct content-type?

Hint 4: How do you create `req.body` from the request stream?

You didn't include the entire code so it's impossible to give you a specific solution.

> What am I doing wrong here?

Whatever you're doing wrong here, it's not included in the question.

> However, if I change my format of post request(same request with additional new lines)

It would be useful if you included more details of how you do it.

I see two potential sources of that problem:

1. either the commas are introduced during the on the client side
2. or they are introduced during the request reading on the server side

You didn't show us any of those two parts - you didn't show the serializing code and the code that sends the data, and you didn't include the code that gets the data, possibly joins it from chunks and parses the JSON. But the problem is likely in one of those parts.

### Update

Here is an example on how to do what you need using Express. You didn't answer whether you use any framework like Express or not, but I think that you should if you can't achieve that simple task without it, so here is a working example:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

function getSearchData(req, res, next) {
  console.log('req body is', req.body);
  console.log('req body JSON is', JSON.stringify(req.body));

  res.json({ ok: true });
}

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(getSearchData);

app.listen(3335, () => console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3335/'));
```

It shows how to correctly get a parsed JSON request body as an object `req.body`, how to print the data as a standard console.log representation and serialized again as JSON. See how it works and compare it to your own solution. This is all I can do because not having seen your entire solution I cannot tell you more than the hints that I've already given.

Comment: Thanks for the reply rsp. I did modify the content of the question. New to stackoverflow as well so struggling a bit with the formatting here. I am using swagger to send the request and just trying to print what the request was. I think for some reason the request itself is not being recognized as a json request and is being read as a string and thus the extra commas.

Comment: I managed to fix the content-type part to application/json but it still gives me the same error. Irrespective if it's a JSON or a String, the new lines are getting converted into commas.                                                                                  `{"parameters":{"id":[96409],"source":["'XYZ'"]}}                        `gets converted to                                                                                                         `{"parameters":{"id":[96409],,"source":["'XYZ'"]}}`

Comment: @user3455306 Your code in the question is still incomplete. You didn't include where the `reqJSON` comes from, you didn't say where your `req.body` comes from, how the request body stream is concatenated, how it is parsed, whether you use any framework like Express and if so whether you use body-parser.

Comment: @user3455306 See the updated answer with a working solution.

Comment: The issue was with the yaml file. It wasn't getting converted into JSON which is eventually being used to process the request. No matter what I changed in yaml the json was still stale resulting in messing up the request being passed. Fixed the yaml and as rightly pointed out by you now I don't even need to parse the json request. Thanks a lot for your inputs.